# output html in multiple lines

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I'm using Skybrud Social to get Instagram feeds.

The caption I got from the feed is something like below:

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
```

When I output it to html it will be

```
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3
```

How do I make it so that it display just like the first?

```
s = CurrentPage;
Skybrud.Social.Umbraco.Instagram.PropertyEditors.OAuth.InstagramOAuthData client = s.ig;
var service = InstagramService.CreateFromAccessToken(client.AccessToken);
var response = service.Tags.GetRecentMedia("invitation",10);
foreach (Skybrud.Social.Instagram.Objects.InstagramMedia mediaig in response.Body.Data)
{
   <div class="col-md-4">    
       <div class="row" >
           <a class="template" href="@mediaig.Link">
               <div class="col-xs-12 templateIconDiv">
                   <div class="templateIconDivContainer">
                       <img class="templateIcon" 
                       src="@mediaig.Images.StandardResolution.Url">
                   </div>        
                   <div class="col-xs-12 templateName">
                       @Html.Raw(mediaig.Caption.Text)
                   </div>              

               </div>
           </a>
       </div>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Use `<br/>` after each line or use `div` to hold each line.

Comment: wrap each line in `<p>`

Comment: and how exactly do I do that?

Comment: First, Provide what you have tried before, post your code.

Comment: just remove first div which has a class col-md-4, it is causing your element inline instead of block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 templateName" style="white-space: pre-line;">
                   @Html.Raw(mediaig.Caption.Text)
               </div>
```